# Rollup UMD output format doesn't work, however ES does

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollupjs

When I output my code as `es` the following works perfectly.

`index.html`

```html
<body>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <script type="module">
    import { BackgroundLayer, Engine } from "./dist/bundle.js";

    const engine = new Engine([new BackgroundLayer(153), new BackgroundLayer(298)]);
    engine.animate();
</script>
</body>
```

`rollup.config.js`

```js
import arraybuffer from "@wemap/rollup-plugin-arraybuffer";
import { babel } from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";

export default {
  input: "src/index.js",
  output: {
    name: "EBB",
    file: "dist/bundle.js",
    format: "es",
  },
  plugins: [
    arraybuffer({ include: "**/*.dat" }), // so Rollup can import .dat files
    resolve(), // so Rollup can find `ms`
    commonjs(), // so Rollup can convert `ms` to an ES module
    terser(), // minifying
    // babel configuration
    babel({
      babelHelpers: "runtime",
      exclude: "**/node_modules/**",
      skipPreflightCheck: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

However, when I change `format` to `umd`, which I kind of need for backwards compatibility on the browser. and change `index.html` to:

```html
<body>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="module">
    const engine = new Engine([new BackgroundLayer(153), new BackgroundLayer(298)]);
    engine.animate();
</script>
```

It displays a blank page, when I check the console it gives an `ReferenceError`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Engine is not defined
```

I have a hypothesis that it might be because of `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`, however, I am not too sure that's what's actually happening here.

Full Code can be found here: https://github.com/IamRifki/earthbound-battle-backgrounds-rollup

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is to call it with the prefix `EBB`, like the `output.name` value suggests.

```html
<body>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <script type="module">
    const engine = new EBB.Engine([new EBB.BackgroundLayer(153), new EBB.BackgroundLayer(298)]);
    engine.animate();
</script>
</body>
```